# How not to get ClassCastException using StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate

I get exception on creating configuration:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl cannot be cast to class javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry (org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')

This is my code with the error:

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

This is my https://github.com/anatoliy19/1.1.4.git

Comment: is there any reason why you have imported `javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry` instead of `org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry` ?

Comment: No reason. Just confused ))